# I can't redirect htaccess slash 301

Tags: .htaccess, seo

when I enter the htaccess code on website.com/seo.php, it redirects to website.com/seo, but I want it to do website.com/seo/

my htaccess codes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Then add a `/` after `%1` in that RewriteRule …?

Comment: @CBroe Unfortunately, I did not understand what you said.

Comment: Go find the `%1` in the code you have shown (it occurs only one single time, so not much ambiguity there), and add a slash at the end of it.

Comment: @ardacar, oh god, just add a `/` after `%1` in the fourth line. See my answer if you are still unable to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead of the current one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

### What I changed:

`RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]` to `RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]` (adding a `/` after `%1`)

Don't forget to clear cache.

Comment: @chi-c-j-rajeeva-lochana Thanks for your answer it worked. I have one more question, can the website.com/seo link forward to website.com/seo/ without breaking this system?

Comment: @ardacar maybe, let me know if any errors occur.

Comment: I tried most of the codes but couldn't. My current htaccess codes are the codes you throw. Can you help me redirect to `website.com/seo/` when I go to `website.com/seo`

Comment: @ardacar Ask a different question. I can't post two answers to the same one.

Comment: @chi-c-j-rajeeva-lochana https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65969835/directing-non-slash-url-to-slash