# Directing Non-Slash URL to Slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

When I enter the `website.com/seo` link, I want to make a 301 redirect to the `website.com/seo/` link. However, I don't want it to be broken in the codes I wrote in the current htaccess.

my htacces codes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use only one of these, do not use together!

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(.*?)\/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

If that doesn't work, use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(.*?)\/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Remove the previous rules, and try once. If it works after removing previous rules, then let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228052/discussion-between-ardacar-and-chi-c-j-rajeeva-lochana).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please clear browser cache before testing your URLs

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```